# Why sed extended regex with plus sign is not working

Tags: bash, sed

I have to fetch major and minor version combined together as one number in bash script.

For example: From 'Python 3.10.2', I need 310

`sed 's/.* \([0-9]\).\([0-9]\).*/\1\2/'` works perfectly when the minor version is **single digit** and it fails when it is **double digit**.
Hence, i tried `sed -E 's/.* \([0-9]+\).\([0-9]+\).*/\1\2/'`. But this throws an error

for example: `echo "Python 3.10.2" | sed -E 's/.* \([0-9]+\).\([0-9]+\).*/\1\2/'` results in an error

As a workaround, i am using `echo "Python 3.10.2" | grep -Eo '[0-9]+.[0-9]+' | sed s/[.]//g`

Is there a way to get what i need in one sed without using grep like how i am doing currently?

Thanks,

Strive

Comment: You could do like: `echo "Python 3.10.2" | awk -F' |\\.' '{print $2 $3}'` to get required output. Also while using `-E` option of `sed` you need not to escape `(` and `)` for capturing groups. So your command like: `echo "Python 3.10.2" | sed -E 's/.* ([0-9]+).([0-9]+).*/\1\2/'` will work fine.

Comment: When using `-E` option the need to use  `\ ` before `+` is removed as is the need to use `\ ` before either `(` ,`)` and `{`,`}` too.

Comment: Don't just state "throws an error" and "results in an error" - show the error message(s) in your question.

Comment: @EdMorton, Sure. Henceforth I will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably getting an error message about `\1` and `\2` not being available/populated since in this code:

```
echo "Python 3.10.2" | sed -E 's/.* \([0-9]+\).\([0-9]+\).*/\1\2/'
```

you're escaping the `(` and `)` that would populate those cap[ture groups. You need to escape them in BREs, but you're using EREs, courtesy of `-E` and so you have to leave them unescaped:

```
$ echo "Python 3.10.2" | sed -E 's/.* ([0-9]+).([0-9]+).*/\1\2/'
310
```

The `.` in the middle of the regexp should really be escaped as `\.`

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you want:

```bash
sed -E 's/^.+ |\.[0-9]*$|\.//g'
```

this removes everything from

1. the beginning uptil a space
2. the end after and including the last dot `.`
3. removes every dot `.` in between